# How to set up automatic Google Support Repository update for Android project?

Tags: android, jenkins, build-tools

**I'm trying to set up automatic Google Support Repository update for my Android project on Jenkins**. I found two ways to do that- **Jake Wharton's SDK Manager Plugin**, or **Android Emulator Plugin for Jenkins**, but both of those solutions seem to be deprecated. The docs for SDK Manager Plugin point out that:

> This plugin is deprecated and is no longer being developed. The Android tools team has committed to automatically downloading tools and dependencies in v2.2.0 and will be improving it in subsequent releases.

Where can I find any information on how to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are the release notes http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system.

Basically that means that upgrading to use:

- `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha4'`

will make that gradle downloads automatically the missing dependencies if you add the experimental flag:

- `android.builder.sdkDownload=true` to your `gradle.properties` file.

You can see the announcement here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csaXml4xtN8&index=23&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc8jQTUYvIfqA9lMvSGQWtte 43:35

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for :) Too bad it's still in alpha, but I will give it a try.

Comment: Excellent answer, but unfortunately it seems this experimental option only downloads build tools and platforms, but doesn't actually update Google or Support repository. Which is a shame and [reported as a bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=212309).